# Cloudera Hue running WordCount

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh, word-count, hue

I have successfully installed and started up the CDH5 manager and agent. However whenever I try running the MR hello world job, ie WordCount, it runs upto 33% and stays in the same condition for a long time and it doesn't proceed.

Any clues as to where it might be going wrong?

FYI, when trying to run in the terminal it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to switch Hue to use the CherryPy server instead of Spawning. In the hue.ini or the Hue Safety Valve in CM, enter:

```
[desktop]
use_cherrypy_server = true
```

These issues may be due to Beeswax crashing or being very slow and blocking all the requests as the Spawing Server is not perfectly greenified

Comment: There is no Spawning server anymore in CDH5

Answer (score 0):

Hue can use Oozie to submit jobs and it requires on more MR task. Usually the problem is that Yarn Apps asks for too much memory in your cluster (so decrease their default resources in yarn config) or it is gotcha #5 http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/04/apache-hadoop-yarn-avoiding-6-time-consuming-gotchas/